# Gradient descent for solving complex-valued $Ax = b$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric positive definite. In this case, solving $Ax = b$ with $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is equivalent to find
\begin{align}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg\min}\ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^{\mathrm{T}}Ax - b^{\mathrm{T}}x.
\end{align}
So, I can use graident descent (GD) method to approximate it as:
\begin{align}
u_i = u_{i-1} - \alpha_{i-1}\nabla f(u_{i-1}) = u_{i-1} + \alpha_{i-1} (b - Au_{i-1}).
\end{align}
where $\alpha_{i-1} = 2 / (\lambda_{\max} + \lambda_{\min})$, $\lambda_{\max}$ and $\lambda_{\min}$ denote the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of $A$.

My question:
Now, consider the complex-valued case, i.e., $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is Hermitian positive definite, and $x,b \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$.
I find that the same GD method can still be used to approximate $x = A^{-1}b$.
However, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^{\mathrm{H}}Ax - b^{\mathrm{H}}x$ is not a function $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, as $b^{\mathrm{H}}x$ is not necessarily real-valued. So, how to explain this point?

Comment: What do you mean by why GD still works? in both cases, GD minimizes the distance between $b$ and the range of the $A$.